Why are tensile strength tests considered as the better method by which we determine yield strength and young's modulus?
I am currently working on a research paper in which I am attempting to investigate young's modulus of different materials but everywhere I go they say to perform a tensile strength test. But the formula could also work for compressive strength tests which is much easier and cheaper to perform.

In a tensile test, you don't have to worry about buckling

How is compressive test cheaper than tensile?

who does compressive tests not on concrete?
